ListPlot of unsorted data
I have two lengthy lists with two columns. I’d like to plot both lists on the same graph using solid and dashed lines. However, the issue is that the points in both lists cannot be sorted in a way that if joined, they form a continuous line. Instead, they are connected by irregular lines that connect points scattered across the plotting area. I’ve attached the images for your reference. Could you please help me resolve this issue?


The data is given here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pr8Y0cWap6t8iAesHF57mzt7eqozRQXa?usp=share_link

Using FindCurvePath might be one place to start, although you'll likely have to tweak the output. Without the data, though, it'll be hard to come up with something that will work for you.

Thanks for your reply. I added the data above.

Your question is unclear.  Does your problem arise even if you have a single list of (unsorted) data?

I think @march 's comment answer's you're question. Example here with your EM data.

@DavidG.Stork. Yes. (at)ydd thank you for your reply. It’s   what I wanted, although the plot could be smoother. Nevertheless, I appreciate your efforts.

Next time, please share your code in InputForm plain text, not images. And provide the data in code ready to be used, stored in permanent location. something along the lines:
a1stableData = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/2xdJFv0n",{ "CSV", "Data"}]
